# Receiving com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: error when loading Byte Data as Response from Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I'm receiving an image from an API call to the server in the form of [Byte data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdWOH.png). But when I receive the Retrofit2 Response it causes the errors stated above. Here's my Application Retrofit Object btw:

```
object RetrofitInstance {
        private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        addInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
        addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
    }.build()
private val retrofit by lazy {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
    }
val api : ApplicationAPI by lazy {
        retrofit.create(ApplicationAPI::class.java)
    }
```

I'm not sure why there's a Json Syntax Exception. I believe it may be because of the gson client I've created? Could someone please help me figure this out. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving

```
addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
```

and add the below line in build.gradle

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're suggesting I switch from Gson to Moshi. But what I did was create an identical RetrofitObject except that I created a Moshi instead of a Gson://

        val moshi = Moshi
                .Builder()
                .addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
                .build()

        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())
            .build()//

My new error:
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected an int but was STRING at path $